# Contravariant Functor as covariant $F: C^{op} \rightarrow D$

Tags: category-theory

I've been having trouble understanding Contravariant functor as being functor from $C^{op}$.

I understand the below definition well(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor):

[image]

But the definition I do not get is

[image]

In particular, I'm confused as to why we are defining $Ff$ where $f: c \rightarrow c' \in C$, when $F$ is a functor from $C^{op}$.

Shouldn't we define $F f^{op}$ where $f^{op}: c \rightarrow c' \in C^{op}$?

Maybe I'm overcomplicating thing, but it seems odd to me that we are defining $F: C^{op} \rightarrow D$ by defining what $F$ does to morphism in $C$, rather than $C^{op}$.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Those two definitions of contravariant functors are equivalent and how one implies the other is very clear. Therefore they ar e just regarded as equivalent.

Comment: A contravariant functor from $C$ to $D$ could be considered either as a covariant functor from $C^{op}$ to $D$, or as a covariant functor from $C$ to $D^{op}$.

Comment: Basically, the answer to your question is yes (although I think you mean $f^{\text{op}}: c' \to c$ since $f: c \to c'$ originally) and this is just one way of defining a contravariant functor. Geoffrey Trang sums up the two possible ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $f: c \rightarrow c'$ is an arrow in $C$ if and only if $f^{\text{op}}: c' \rightarrow c$ is an arrow in $C^{\text{op}}$, so defining $F$ on arrows in $C$ is equivalent to defining $F$ on arrows in $C^{\text{op}}$.

Comment: That helped, thanks!